# JOIN 3 tables and (LIMIT 2 rows ORDER BY time DESC)

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by, limit

I know this question has been asked many times, but I am having trouble implementing it.
I have made a cut down example so its easy to reproduce.
I want to join 3 tables but on the last one I want to limit to 2 rows DESC

```
CREATE TABLE `cars` (
`car_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`plate` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`km` int(11) NOT NULL,
`status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
INSERT INTO `cars` (`car_id`, `plate`, `km`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'ABC1234', 130123, 1),
(2, 'DEF1234', 100123, 1),
(3, 'QWE1234', 5000, 1),
(4, 'ASD1234', 3000, 1),
(5, 'ZXC1234', 23000, 0);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `cars_to_users` (
`car_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `car_id` (`car_id`,`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `cars_to_users` (`car_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 2),
(4, 2),
(5, 2);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `service` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`car_plate` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`s_timestamp` int(10) NOT NULL,
`price` double NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=111 ;
INSERT INTO `service` (`id`, `car_plate`, `s_timestamp`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 'ABC1234', 1312300100, 30),
(2, 'DEF1234', 1312300100, 15),
(3, 'QWE1234', 1312300100, 16),
(4, 'ASD1234', 1312300100, 50),
(5, 'ABC1234', 1312300200, 50),
(6, 'DEF1234', 1312300200, 25),
(7, 'QWE1234', 1312300200, 30),
(8, 'ABC1234', 1312300300, 20),
(9, 'ASD1234', 1312300300, 60),
(10, 'ABC1234', 1312300400, 15),
(11, 'ASD1234', 1312300400, 20);
```

What I want is this

```
car_id  plate  km  car_plate  s_timestamp  price  
3 QWE1234 5000 QWE1234 1312300200 30 
3 QWE1234 5000 QWE1234 1312300100 16 
4 ASD1234 3000 ASD1234 1312300400 20 
4 ASD1234 3000 ASD1234 1312300300 60
```

2 rows from "service" table for every car of the user_id=2 ordered by s_timestamp DESC

```
ORDER BY s_timestamp LIMIT 2 DESC
```

I try this query but gives me all the rows from "service"

```
SELECT ctu.user_id, c.car_id, c.plate, c.km, s.car_plate, s.s_timestamp, s.price
FROM cars_to_users ctu 
LEFT JOIN cars c ON  ctu.car_id = c.car_id
LEFT JOIN service s ON c.plate = s.car_plate 
WHERE ctu.user_id = '2' 
AND c.status = 1
```

If I add "GROUP BY c.car_id" I only get 1 row per car and not 2 I want

I try many queries but not get what I want.

A thing to keep in mind is that the table "service" has more than 9 million rows and more data than the example, and grows up.

Comment: what is the version of mysql that you are using as you said limit doesnt work on your version???

Comment: Were you able to use my statements, using temp tables should make it a bit faster.

Comment: @ace Your solution works great too. But if the same thing can be achieved in through a sub query and the number of rows to be retrieved in the subquery/temp table is only 2, why not use subquery instead.

Comment: @reggie, Temp tables have the advantage when running the query multiple times because the data is already generated. Running a query with a subquery handling 9 million rows at a time is overkill, compared to having a temp table that is already trimmed down to maybe 20% of 9 million records because we only get the top 2 for each car plate.

Comment: @ace Thanks for the advice. I learnt something today :)

Comment: @reggie, no problem. I learnt something new too, didn't know it was easy in MSSQL and in higher versions of MySQL.

Comment: I have too versions 5.0.51 and 5.1.35. I test on both with the same results until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is quite complicated. And I'm not sure how well it will perform on your database.

```
SELECT ctu.user_id, c.car_id, c.plate, c.km, s.car_plate, s.s_timestamp, s.price
FROM cars_to_users ctu 
LEFT JOIN cars c ON  ctu.car_id = c.car_id
LEFT JOIN service s ON c.plate = s.car_plate
JOIN 
(
  SELECT service.car_plate,max(service.s_timestamp) as s_timestamp
  FROM service
  JOIN 
  (
    SELECT car_plate, max(s_timestamp) as s_timestamp FROM service GROUP BY car_plate
  ) as max_timestamp ON max_timestamp.car_plate = service.car_plate AND service.s_timestamp < max_timestamp.s_timestamp
  GROUP BY service.car_plate
) as max_2_timestamp ON s.car_plate = max_2_timestamp.car_plate AND s.s_timestamp >= max_2_timestamp.s_timestamp
WHERE ctu.user_id = '2' 
AND c.status = 1
ORDER BY s_timestamp DESC
```

I guess you can put the 2 sub queries in a temp table first like this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS max_timestamp;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS max_2_timestamp;

CREATE TEMPORARY table max_timestamp SELECT car_plate, max(s_timestamp) as s_timestamp FROM service GROUP BY car_plate;

CREATE TEMPORARY table max_2_timestamp
(
  SELECT service.car_plate,max(service.s_timestamp) as s_timestamp
  FROM service
  JOIN max_timestamp ON max_timestamp.car_plate = service.car_plate AND service.s_timestamp < max_timestamp.s_timestamp
  GROUP BY service.car_plate
);

SELECT ctu.user_id, c.car_id, c.plate, c.km, s.car_plate, s.s_timestamp, s.price
FROM cars_to_users ctu 
LEFT JOIN cars c ON  ctu.car_id = c.car_id
LEFT JOIN service s ON c.plate = s.car_plate
JOIN max_2_timestamp ON s.car_plate = max_2_timestamp.car_plate AND s.s_timestamp >= max_2_timestamp.s_timestamp
WHERE ctu.user_id = '2' 
AND c.status = 1
ORDER BY s_timestamp DESC;
```

**EDIT**: Another Alternative

You will only have one query but I can't check if it's **efficient** enough in your system.
Let's create the function that will retrieve the 2nd most recent `s_timestamp` for each `car_plate` in `Service`

```
CREATE FUNCTION LatestService (car_plate varchar(10))
RETURNS int(10)
RETURN 
(SELECT s_timestamp
FROM service s
WHERE s.car_plate=`car_plate`
ORDER BY s.s_timestamp desc
LIMIT 1,1);
```

Then you can perform the query using the function.

```
SELECT ctu.user_id, c.car_id, c.plate, c.km, s.car_plate, s.s_timestamp, s.price
FROM cars_to_users ctu 
LEFT JOIN cars c ON  ctu.car_id = c.car_id
LEFT JOIN service s ON c.plate = s.car_plate 
WHERE ctu.user_id = '2' 
AND c.status = 1
AND s.s_timestamp >= LatestService(s.car_plate);
```

Comment: The complicated (maybe stupid?) part in my query is to get the 2nd_max timestamp for each car_plate. Since I can't think of a way to do this at the moment, I had to run max(timestamp) twice, with the second max(timestamp) less than the 1st max(timestamp). Once you have the 2nd max timestamp, you can generate the query. My way of getting the result set is very horrible if you plan to get the top 3 or more. :)

Comment: The 1st one work as I want in the example, but in real life table(9mil-rows) take about 35sec to complite - so it out of scope. If I take the car_plates from the fisrt 2 tables and make a php foreach loop for every plate like (SELECT * FROM service WHERE car_plate = '$plate' ORDER BY timestamp_3 DESC LIMIT 2) I have about 5sec to complite for 4 cars, BUT I don't want to make 4+1 queries but 1 query and I beleve that the 5secs can be optimized too.

Comment: Does generating the temporary tables take too long too?

Comment: to 2nd one gives an error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT ctu.user_id, c.car_id, c.plate, c.km, s.car_plate, s.s_timestamp, s.price' at line 1

Comment: Edited it, it's because of the missing semicolon.

Comment: have this work for you? now the 2nd gives : "#1146 - Table 'test_join.max_timestamp' doesn't exist." and if I change max_timestamp with max_2_timestamp gives : "#1146 - Table 'test_join.max_2_timestamp' doesn't exist" ....Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, let me edit. I may have given you a mix of my test runs. MY bad.

Comment: Yes the 2nd work too and better than the 1st, it take about 30sec. Not so good as I expect to be.

Comment: After **I ADD INDEX (car_plate, s_timestamp)** the all proccess speed up and now it take **17sec** for the **1st** and **12sec** for the **2nd** query.

But again its to much time (consider that the cpu its **100%** in both queries until they finish)

And consider that now after the Indexing, the aproach with the php foreach loop for the same job takes about **0.033sec**

Comment: I though that (if 1 user has 50 cars) why to have 50+1 queries and not **1 efficient query**. I though it will be better and will speed up the performance but all my tests say the opposite.

Comment: Due to the limitation with the MySQL version, you can't have this as 1 efficient query. I'm thinking of having a view that minimizes your TABLE `service` (to around 50% or less) instead of having to query `service` itself that contains 9 million rows.

Comment: The 3th alternative looks very promising, but in a cut down version of (100.000rows) it takes about 24secs + cpu100%, I am not even think to run it on the big db.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by some id, and add 'HAVING COUNT(some_id) < 2'

http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Select-Clause/UseCOUNTGROUPandHAVING.htm

Comment: I try with GROUP BY s.id HAVING COUNT( s.id ) <2 but I get 5 rows and I try GROUP BY s.s_timestamp HAVING COUNT( s.s_timestamp ) <2 but I get 3 row. What I want is 4 rows and DESC the s_timestamp

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
LEFT JOIN service s ON c.plate = s.car_plate
```

with

```
LEFT JOIN service s on s.id 
  in (SELECT s2.id FROM service s2
      WHERE s2.car_plate=c.plate
      ORDER BY s2.s_timestamp DESC LIMIT 2)
```

I know this will work in MS Sql Server, not 100% sure about mysql.

(EDIT) And as commented below, it doesn't. The workaround is a little ugly (but not too bad) and is described here:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,416311,416461#msg-416461

Comment: It has this error in mysql 5.1.51 `Error Code: 1235
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: After posting that I was looking at the reference to see if it was or wasn't supported, and see also that it's not. There may be a workaround. I'll edit if there's one that's not prohibitively complicated.